# Undefined symbols for architecture arm v7

Tags: iphone, ios

I am getting this error any solution please ?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FacebookSDK(FBSettings.o)
```

Comment: Have you linked with AdSupport framework?

Comment: Thank you @alex-i for your support... Actually did not added this framework.

Comment: dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/FA7B44B5-7E96-4A0E-AF2E-46C3EE7C5F77/Zad-e-Rah.app/ <br> Now i am getting this error after adding AdSupportFramework.

Comment: see @Amar's answer for the second error. If your app supports iOS 5, you need to sent the framework as optional.

Answer (score 2):

You need to link your application with `AdSupport.framework`. This framework is available in iOS6.0 and later. If your application is targeted to use iOS versions less than 6.0 then you need to link to `AdSupport.framework` as **Optional** instead of **Required**.

[image]

---

The Facebook developers page mentions the steps to upgrade your FB SDK. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-from-3.0-to-3.1/. You can find the list of URLs for various SDK versions on this page.

[image]

Check it out.

Hope that helps!

Comment: dyld: Symbol not found: _ACFacebookAppIdKey
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/FA7B44B5-7E96-4A0E-AF2E-46C3EE7C5F77/Zad-e-Rah.app/Zad-e-Rah 
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
 in /var/mobile/Applications/FA7B44B5-7E96-4A0E-AF2E-46C3EE7C5F77/Zad-e-Rah.app/Zad-e-Rah                                            After setting required to optional this error occurs :(

Comment: @MehmoodHassan As suggested in the error, you should also add `Accounts.framework` and set it to Optional as well.

Comment: @MehmoodHassan Here's the link to Facebook developers page which explains the settings. On the left hand there's a list of links to various FB SDKs settings. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-from-3.0-to-3.1/

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't add AdSupport.framework. Also remember to remove -all_load linker flag.

Comment: @MehmoodHassan if its useful then upvote answer and accept the answer

Comment: dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/FA7B44B5-7E96-4A0E-AF2E-46C3EE7C5F77/Zad-e-Rah.app/ <br> Now i am getting this error after adding AdSupportFramework.

Answer (score 1):

The message hints can't find the class `ASIdentifierManager`, because the corresponding framework not really add it to the object. Just add the framework which includes the class.